# Redirect multilingual TYPO3 URLs (L=1)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, typo3, multilingual

I've made a new TYPO3 Website, `english` and `japanese`. The second language isn't ready yet, but the pages are available in google search. My problem the pages with the language parameter `L` should temporary not be visible.

How can I redirect the pages f.e. `http://domain.com/index.php?id=123&L=1`to the main URL `http://domain.com/`

I've tried sth. like this .. but that wasn't correct. I need a bit of help for the RewriteCond/Rule at `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^L=([1-9a-z_-]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

--

I think there's still a problem with the extension `realURL` In english `http://domain.com/news` is visible, but in spite of japanese `http://domain.com/ニュース` will be still visible, too. It's impossible to hide all the second language pages, isn't it?

Comment: Just to note, don't use 301 redirects. Those are permanent ! Use 302, which is a temporary redirect. Going off that the pages are not avail *yet*, I imagine you want them to be in the future :)

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I should use 302 redirect. but how? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what you're after, I think you require a temporary `302` redirect for those URLs. You can do that using:

```
# If you know the directory.
Redirect 302 /directory.html http://domain.com/

#Using the URL
Redirect 302 http://domain.com/index.php?id=123&L=1 http://domain.com/
```

Make sure to clear your cache before testing these.

Comment: I know the typical redirect commands in `htaccess`but in this case, I've approx. 200-300 pages of my website. I can write 200 redirects, but it must be sth. like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`..?! Sth. easier ;)

Comment: I think it's wrong to redirect the standard TYPO3 URLs (`index.php?id=23?L=1`), so the Editors haven't see the preview anymore. I can redirect the 'realURLs', like `Redirect 302 /jp http://www.domain.com/` --- this help me at  the moment ... thanks for your hind with 302 instead of 301.